# Is it possible to find which nodes a relationship connects - Cypher Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher Neo4J query:

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user="9d6e7140-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7") 
RETURN rel;
```

I get the result of the kind:

```
| :TO[268131]
{uid:"9d7d8c73-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7",
timestamp:"14027507237670000",
context:"9d72b702-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7",
user:"9d6e7140-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7",
statement:"9d7d8c70-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7",weight:"3",gapscan:"2"} |
```

(this is a fragment)

Do you know how I can also extract in the same query the information about which actual nodes each relationship connects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher has a function called `STARTNODE` and `ENDNODE` doing the job:

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user="9d6e7140-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7") 
RETURN STARTNODE(rel), ENDNODE(rel);
```